# Converting morse in java

Tags: java, user-interface, morse-code

I am creating a program that converts english to morse. I currently have english-morse(using a hashmap) and two text boxes to get user input and then show result. I have no idea how to do the actual converting without file import. Right now i have set the 2nd action perform label equal to the map (i figured this was wrong but it was worth the attempt). I understand that i need to use a string builder but i dont know how to use it. My question is, how do i attempt to fix this issue?

these are my text fields:

```
    text1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //text box for user
    {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
       String input = text2.getText();
       label.setText(input);
     }
   });

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //convert to morse (text box)
     {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
       String input = text1.getText();
       label.setText(charToCode);
       }
     });
```

here is my english-morse

```
//morse code
Map<Character,String> charToCode = new HashMap<Character,String>();
charToCode.put('A', ".-");
charToCode.put('B', "-...");
charToCode.put('C', "-.-.");
charToCode.put('D', "-..");
charToCode.put('E', ".");
charToCode.put('F', "..-.");
charToCode.put('G', "--.");
charToCode.put('H', "....");
charToCode.put('I', "....");
charToCode.put('J', ".---");
charToCode.put('K', "-.-");
charToCode.put('L', ".-..");
charToCode.put('M', "--");
charToCode.put('N', "-.");
charToCode.put('O', "---");
charToCode.put('P', ".--.");
charToCode.put('Q', "--.-");
charToCode.put('R', ".-.");
charToCode.put('S', "...");
charToCode.put('T', "-");
charToCode.put('U', "..-");
charToCode.put('V', "...-");
charToCode.put('W', "..-");
charToCode.put('X', "-..-");
charToCode.put('Y', "-.--");
charToCode.put('Z', "--..");
```

thanks for your time lads.

Comment: Could you please explain the problem in more detail? Didn't get it yet. Stringbuilder is easy to use but what exactly is your plan?

Comment: You need to get all the chars from the english input textfield, then get the corresponding morse string from the map, and concatenate all these morse strings to have the complete translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at each character in your English string, looking up the morse translation in your map, and appending the translation in a string builder instanciation.  Here's a simple example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(char c : englishString.getChars())
{
    builder.append(translationMap.get(c.toString().toUpperCase()));
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

I hope this helps!